# Line integration: $t^{2}-t$ along $\mathbb{V} (x^{2}-y)$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The plane curve $\langle t,t^{2} \rangle$ is defined by the vanishing of the polynomial $f(x,y)=x^{2}-y$. I want to check if the integral of $f(x,y) = x^{2}-y$ over the curve is equal to $0$. Using the line integration formula: $\int_{0}^{2} (t^{2}-t) \sqrt{(2t)^{2} +1}dt$, the answer turned out to be $\sim 2.7$ rather than $0$. Not like what I was expecting..

Why doesn't the integrand $t^{2}-t$ or $x^{2}-y$ equal zero along the points where $x^{2}-y$ does equal zero?

Comment: $\int_{0}^{2}f(t,t^2)ds$ does equal $0$. I think you evaluated $f(t,t^2)$ incorrectly and forgot a set of parentheses in your integral.

Comment: How do you come up with $t^2 - t$?

Comment: $y=x^{2} \rightarrow x^{2}-y = f(x,y)$

Comment: Are you saying that $x=y$...? That's the only way I see the term $t^2-t$.

Comment: All that I know how to do is substitute $\langle t, t^2 \rangle \hookrightarrow x^{2} - y$ so that gives $t^{2}-t$.

Comment: $f(t,t^2)=t^2-t^2=0$, not $t^2-t$.

Comment: @Matthew Holder and John Hughes you're right i forgot to put $t^{2}$ for $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line integral should be
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^2 f(x(t), y(t)) \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} ~ dt\\
&= \int_0^2 (x(t)^2 -  y(t)) \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} ~ dt & \text{def'n of $f$}\\
&= \int_0^2 (t^2 -  t^2) \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} ~ dt & \text{defn of $x(t), y(t)$}\\
&= \int_0^2 0 \cdot \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} ~ dt & \text{algebra}\\
&= \int_0^2 0 \cdot \sqrt{1^2 + (2t)^2} ~ dt & \text{replace $x', y'$}\\
&= \int_0^2 0 \cdot \sqrt{1 + 4t^2} ~ dt & \text{algebra}\\
&= \int_0^2 0  ~ dt & \text{algebra}\\
&= 0 & \text{FTC}
\end{align}